# creating custom back button in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

My default ionic back button was not showing in nested views so I decided to create custom back button for those pages.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
 <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="goBack()"><i class="ion-android-arrow-back" style="font-size:30px;" ></i></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

My controller function:

```
 $scope.goBack = function() {
        $state.go('app.home');
    };
```

however this logic is working the problem is that, my custom back button is not showing the animation which ionic back button shows on going back. so how can I achieve that animation using my custom back button.

**Also if anybody can tell me some other workarounds for this situation.**

Answer (score 0):

There should be something messing up with the history if the button isn't showing up. But if you have to take an alternative path, first try using the [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

```
 $scope.goBack = function() {
     $ionicHistory.goBack();
 };
```

If it doen't work out, try using

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
  $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection("backward");
  $state.go('app.home');
};
```